# How to include my Index.html in webpack Production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have the following index.html in the root of my project that simply uses the bundled js and css files.

```
    <html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Purchasing Plus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./build/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mountPoint"></div>
    <script src="./build/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my WebPack Config`

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var extractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: { main: './source/scripts/main.js' },

    output: {
        filename: './build/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss?|css)$/,
                loader: extractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass'),
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new extractTextPlugin('./build/style.css', {
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false },
            mangle: true,
            sourcemap: false,
            beautify: false,
            dead_code: true
        })
    ]
};
```

This works great for a web pack dev I can run webpack-dev-server and my page is displayed at http://localhost:8080/

The problem is that I would like to include the index.html in my production build such that I end up with bundle.js, style.css and index.html all sitting next to each other in the build folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use [copy-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin). This will help your to copy a static file from one location to other.

```
{
    from: 'path/to/index.html',
    to: 'build/',
    toType: 'file'
},
```

Other solution is to use [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader). This will test for the given extension and move the file to the given location. You need to add `index.html` to the webpack entry.

```
{
    test: /\.html?$/,
    loader: "file?name=./[name].[ext]"
}
```

Hope this helps!